# Cannot read property undefined doesn't throw an exception in my Scratch org

Tags: aura

I'm developing aura components and faced with strange behaviour which is if there is undefined object in my code and I try to get property of this undefined object it doesn't trigger an exception in my own Scratch org, but it does in another QA org. Can I somehow to force it to throw all JS exception in my Scratch org? I want to have similar JS behaviour both in my Scratch and QA org if it is possible.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Without looking at the code, this is hard to guess. I would guess that in your scratch org you have data that you don't have in your QA. But pure guess work.

Comment: Code is pretty simle, something like that:                                                                    
var record = component.get("v.record");
var index = record.index; //this line throws exception only in QA org, see screenshot attached. This exception window is not showing in my scratch org.

Comment: it is not null, it's undefined in both orgs, in my scratch org and in QA org, but it doesn't throw an exception window in my scratch org

Comment: How about including the code you have developed for the aura components so we can eliminate the guess work?